# Laravel eloquent data

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, job-scheduling

I am trying to send some input data to a job to process in Laravel 8. Following is my controller function

```
public function saveOrder(Request $request){
$orderDetails = $this->validate($request,[
   'customer_name'=> 'required|max:255',
   'customer_mobile' => 'required|max:10',
   'deliver_address' => 'required'
]);

  $order_total = 100.00;
  $order_no = 'O-14587';

  OrdersSaveJob::dispatch($orderDetails);
}
```

But I want to add $order_total and $order_no to the $orderDetails before sending this data to job. Can someone help me to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try convert array to collection and merge() method like this:

```
$collection = collect($orderDetails)
$merged = $collection->merge(['order_total' => 100.00, 'order_no' => 'O-14587']);
OrdersSaveJob::dispatch($merged);
```

Comment: I tried your approach. But I got this error
Error
' Call to a member function merge() on array "